# select count by value

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a table `messages` with the following fields:

```
id          | Number
customer_id | Number
source      | VARCHAR2
...
```

I want to know how many messages each customer has, but I want to differentiate between messages where `source` equals to `'xml'` and all other sources.

My query so far

```
SELECT customer_id,
  case when source = 'xml' then 'xml' else 'manual' end as xml,
  count(*)
FROM MESSAGES
GROUP BY customer_id, 
  case when source = 'xml' then 'xml' else 'manual' end;
```

which gives me a result similar to this:

```
customer_id | xml    | count
----------------------------
1           | xml    |    12
1           | manual |    34
2           | xml    |    54
3           | xml    |    77
3           | manual |     1
...
```

This is rather ugly in two ways:

1. I have to repeat the `case` statement in both the field list and in the group list
2. I now have two rows per customer.

Q: Is it possible to formulate a query, such that the result looks like this instead?

```
customer_id | xml | manual
--------------------------
1           |  12 |     34
2           |  54 |      0
3           |  11 |      1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT customer_id,
  sum(case when source = 'xml' then 1 else 0 end) as xml,
  sum(case when source <> 'xml' then 1 else 0 end) as manual
FROM MESSAGES
GROUP BY customer_id
```

This assumes the `source` column is non `null`. If it can be `null` use `coalesce` or `nvl` in the `case` expression so the comparison gives you expected results.

Comment: It doesn't mention a source called 'manual' just everything that isn't xml

Comment: This will miss the case when source is NULL. The OP should state how those should be counted. If they are "other" then it's easiest to change the second `case` to `case when source = 'xml' then 0 else 1 end`

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT customer_id,
       count(case when source = 'xml' then 1 end) as xml_count, 
       count(case when source <> 'xm' then 1 end) as manual_count
FROM MESSAGES
GROUP BY customer_id
```

This works because aggregates ignore `NULL` values and the result of the `CASE` will be `NULL` if `source` does not contain the value from the case condition.

Answer (score 1):

This will work, it doesn't appear you have a source called 'manual'. COUNT or SUM will give you the same difference.

```
SELECT
    customer_id
    ,ISNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN source = 'xml' THEN 1 END),0) xml
    ,ISNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN source <> 'xml' OR source IS NULL THEN 1 END),0) manual
FROM Messages
GROUP BY customer_id
```

This will allow for zero to appear where you usually would see a NULL value, your sample has a zero rather than a null.

Comment: ISNULL isn't an Oracle function; you could use NVL or COALESCE, but `count()` won't return null anyway.

Comment: Aah, didn't notice the oracle tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fancy solution (it does almost exactly what vkp's solution does), using the PIVOT operation introduced in Oracle 11.1. Note how the distinction between 'xml' and all others (including NULL) is dealt with in the subquery.

```
select *
from (select customer_id, case when source = 'xml' then 'xml' else 'other' as source
      from messages)
pivot (count(*) for source in ('xml' as xml, 'other' as other))
;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is other way by using decode function apart from CASE:

```
 SELECT cust_id,
  COUNT(DECODE(source,'xml','xml'))"XML",
  COUNT(DECODE(source,'manual','manual'))"manual"
FROM MESSAGES
GROUP BY cust_id;
```

But, this won't show result when you have null as source.